# Google Maps API - Getting closest points to zipcode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm in the process of adding a map to a website using Google Maps API v3 and javascript.

I have a list of addresses and have successfully plotted them on the map. When the user types in a zip code, the map re-centers on their location showing the markers closest to that point. Now, I need to create a list view of the closest 3 or 5 locations to their zip code with links for driving direction. I'm stuck...and open for suggestions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual solution is to use the [google.maps.geometry.spherical library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) computeDistanceBetween(from:LatLng, to:LatLng, radius?:number) method to reduce the number to about 10, then use the [distance matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) return the driving distance to those locations so the results can be sorted by driving distance (actual travel distance), and reduced to the closest 3 to 5 locations by actual travel distance within the request limits.

[example (finds the 3 closest places from a list)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlaces.html)
(data borrowed from the FusionTables "pizza store" example)

```
  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
        customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,10);
        // get driving distance
        closest = closest.splice(0,3);
        calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,3);
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {
   var closest = [];
   document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing "+gmarkers.length+"<br>";
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
     gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process "+i+":"+gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+":"+gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2)+"<br>";
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
     closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
   }
   closest.sort(sortByDist);
   return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a,b) {
   return (a.distance- b.distance)
}

function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request =    {
      origins: [pt],
      destinations: [],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    };
  for (var i=0; i<closest.length; i++) request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfResults; i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest["+i+"],\"click\");'>"+closest[i].title + '</a><br>' + closest[i].address+"<br>"
            + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately '
            + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr>';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[example above with "Get Directions" link in the infoWindow](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlacesDirections.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you have the lat lng pair of a zipcode you can use the harversine formula to find the distance from your location.