# How can I find places close to given place list via google geocoding API

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, geocoding, google-places-api

I have a list of doctors with addresses and zip codes  and lat+lng,
I want to send my location (lat+lng) or zip and get all the near by doctors via google geocoding API

how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - Getting closest points to zipcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280787/google-maps-api-getting-closest-points-to-zipcode)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call any API for that. All you need to do is to calculate the distances between your location and doctors using a straightforward [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and make selection from the list based on that. If your data is stored in a database, most commercial databases offer spatial extensions which encapsulate distance calculations and support spatial indexes to speed up selections from large lists.