# map.fitBounds to nearest 5 markers to the myLocation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the myLocation and a set of markers.  I can successfully use fitBounds to display them all.

I want to zoom/fitbounds in to the myLocation plus the nearest 5 markers (to myLocation).

If i had the nearest 5, I could iterate thru them and `bounds.extend(latlng);` each one of them, and the myLocation.  (I think)

How do I find the nearest 5?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  What's your question, how to calculate the 5 nearest markers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - Closest marker function change to closest n markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905570/google-maps-api-closest-marker-function-change-to-closest-n-markers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did, on advice from [Google Maps API - Closest marker function change to closest n markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905570/google-maps-api-closest-marker-function-change-to-closest-n-markers)

```
function sortByDist(a, b) {
    return (a.distance - b.distance)
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
    var closest = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, markers[i].getPosition());
        closest.push(markers[i]);
    }
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
    return closest.splice(0,numberOfResults);
}


closest = findClosestN(urHeremarker.position, 5);
for(i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(closest[i].position);
}
bounds.extend(urHeremarker.position);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```