# Dynamically set Google Maps zoom level to show a minimum / maximum number of POIs

Tags: google-maps, zooming

In our app, store location POIs are scattered across the country, and our map lets users find stores near them. However there is no single zoom level that works for all users - users whose locations are in large urban centers get 100's of POIs, and rural users can get 0 with the same zoom level.

We have attempted to use the dynamic "city" level zoom, but it's still far too zoomed out in urban centers.

The best user experience is to have the zoom level set itself dynamically based on a minimum and maximum number of POIs. That way all users have at least 1 and not more than 10 POIs on their map to start out with.

To provide 2 concrete examples:

- User in the countryside visits the map. Because they are remote, the zoom level is very zoomed-out - enough to get the 1 or 2 closest POIs in view (50 km radius).
- User in a big urban center visits the map. Because it's a big city with lots of POIs, zoom level is very zoomed in. They see up to 10 POIs within a 10 km radius.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Find the user's location.
- Process through the list of POIs finding the 10 closest to the user.
  (related question: [Google Maps API - Closest marker function change to closest n markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905570/google-maps-api-closest-marker-function-change-to-closest-n-markers))
- Zoom to show the bounds of those 10 closest POIs.