# Google Maps JavaScript API Get Lat/Lng from another function and push to Street View Image API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280787/google-maps-api-getting-closest-points-to-zipcode) for getting closest points on the map and displaying them.

```
function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {

    var closest = [];

    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
         gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
         gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
         closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
       }
       closest.sort(sortByDist);
       return closest;
    }

    function sortByDist(a,b) {
       return (a.distance- b.distance)
    }

    function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      var request =    {
          origins: [pt],
          destinations: [],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        };
      for (var i=0; i<closest.length; i++) request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
      service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
          alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else { 

          var origins = response.originAddresses;
          var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
          var outputDiv = document.getElementById('search_results');
          outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

          photo_lat = closest[i].lat; // lat
          photo_lng = closest[i].lng; // lng

          profile_photo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + photo_lat + "," + photo_lng + "&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76";

          var results = response.rows[0].elements;
          for (var i = 0; i < numberOfResults; i++) {
            closest[i].setMap(map);
            outputDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='location_list' style='background:url(" + profile_photo + ");'>" + "<div class='inner'>" + "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest["+i+"],\"click\");'>"+closest[i].title + '</a><br>' + closest[i].address+"<br>"
                + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately '
                + results[i].duration.text
                + "</div></div>";
          }
        }
      });

}
```

In the calculateDistances method, I'd now like to get the lat and lng values for each of the "closest" results. Then I would like to pass each of these lat/lng pairs into the Street View Image API to display a static street view image of each location:

```
photo_lat = closest[i].lat; // lat
photo_lng = closest[i].lng; // lng
```

closest[i] doesn't seem to be the correct target though. How can I extract the lat/lng from each "closest" result within the method?

```html
<style>
    
html { 
 height: 100%;
}

body { 
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 26px;
    font-family: "filson-soft";
}

#map_container {
    height: 700px;
}

#map {
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
}

#locations_list {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: left;
}
    
.location_list {
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: 100% !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}

#search_results {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#search_results .inner {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 60px;
} 
    
</style>

<div id="map_container">

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="locations_list">

        <div id="search_results"></div>

    </div>
    
</div>
      
<script>

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var locations;
    var gmarkers = [];
    var closest = [];
    var search_lat;
    var search_lng;
    var infowindow;
    var directionsDisplay; 
    var directionsService;

    function initMap() {

        gmarkers = [];

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;  
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        // SET THE CENTER OF THE MAP

        var theCenter = {
            lat: 38.5803844, 
            lng: -121.50024189999999
        };

        // ADD THE MAP AND SET THE MAP OPTIONS

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: theCenter
        });

        locations = [
            ["Joes Parking Garage","1001 6th St","Sacramento","CA","95814","38.58205649","-121.49857521","parking_garage"],
            ["Mikes Parking Garage","918 5th St","Sacramento","CA","95814","38.5826939","-121.50012016","parking_garage"]
        ];

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        console.log("found " + locations.length + " locations<br>");

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            var icon_image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/parkinglot.png';

            var coordStr = locations[i][5] + "," + locations[i][6];
            var coords = coordStr.split(",");
            var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));
            bounds.extend(pt);

            var location_name = locations[i][0];
            var location_address = locations[i][1] + ', ' + locations[i][2] + ', ' + locations[i][3] + ' ' + locations[i][4];

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pt,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: icon_image,
                map: map,
                title: location_name,
                address: location_address
            });

            gmarkers.push(marker);
            
        }

        var address = "547 L St, Sacramento, CA 95814";

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                search_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                search_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                console.log('search address coordinates: ' + search_lat + ', ' + search_lng);

                closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,10);
                // get driving distance
                closest = closest.splice(0,10);
                calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,10);

                //calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

            } else {

                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

            }

        });

    }

    function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {
       var closest = [];
       //document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing "+gmarkers.length+"<br>";
       for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
         gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
        // document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process "+i+":"+gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+":"+gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2)+"<br>";
         gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
         closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
       }
       closest.sort(sortByDist);
       return closest;
    }

    function sortByDist(a,b) {
       return (a.distance- b.distance);
    }

    function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      var request =    {
          origins: [pt],
          destinations: [],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        };
      for (var i=0; i<closest.length; i++) request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
      service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
          alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else { 

          var origins = response.originAddresses;
          var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
          var outputDiv = document.getElementById('search_results');
          outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

          var results = response.rows[0].elements;
          for (var i = 0; i < numberOfResults; i++) {
            closest[i].setMap(map);



          photo_lat = closest[i].getPosition().lat(); // lat
          photo_lng = closest[i].getPosition().lng(); // lng

          profile_photo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?sensor=false&size=600x300&location=" + photo_lat + "," + photo_lng + "&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76";


            outputDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='location_list' style='background:url(" + profile_photo + ");'>" + "<div class='inner'>" + "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest["+i+"],\"click\");'>"+closest[i].title + '</a><br>' + closest[i].address+"<br>"
                + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately '
                + results[i].duration.text
                + "</div></div>";
          }
        }
      });
    }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: @geocodezip here is the minimal, complete tested and readable example you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the `closest` array are [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) objects.  To get their location, call their `.getPosition()` method (returns a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) object).

```
photo_lat = closest[i].getPosition().lat(); // lat
photo_lng = closest[i].getPosition().lng(); // lng
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosition' of undefined" with this code.

Comment: That implies that `closest[i]`is undefined.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: here is the minimal, complete tested and readable example you asked for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you expect `i` to be?  How are you using `photo_lat` & `photo_lng`? Currently `i` isn't defined, you are accessing outside of any of the loops that iterate through the arrays.  I would think you would want to move that inside the loop that is showing the closest "n" markers.

Comment: Thanks.. ugh.. miss these things sometimes.