# How can I load a list of locations into Google Maps and then search for the nearest locations via a given city/zip?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to load a list of locations (Name and Address) into Google Maps, and then query it to find all nearest locations when given a city or a zipcode?

For instance, I have a list of stores:

Store1
123 ocean blvd
Venice, CA, 91123

Store2
123 store blvd
New York, NY, 12345

and so on...

Now, I load it to Google Maps / Places?...

And then I want to query the API by passing in a given location (zip, state, or city), and find all the stores that are nearest to it.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Google Maps API - Getting closest points to zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280787/google-maps-api-getting-closest-points-to-zipcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can to use GMSGeocoder, Its give you opportunity find  location full address , zip cod , state country and city .

Comment: Please add here the additional insight your recent addtional answer provides, by [edit]ing here. That way your contribution is not lost in case that other answer gets deleted for being barely more than a link. Then you can delete the other, practically link-only answer yourself.

Answer (score -1):

if you use google map, it's GMSGeocoder property.

// for iOS implementation ...

private func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()

geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
guard let address = response?.firstResult(), let lines = address.lines else {
return
}
}
}

Comment: Please move this and make it an addtion to your 2 year old other answer. The combination will make a much nicer answer than any of the two alone. Then delete this post.